# Sharing Java model classes between Eclipse (Maven) and Android Studio (Gradle)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have created a Java webservice in Eclipse which provides a REST API and an Android project (in Android Studio) which consumes said API. The problem I am facing right now is that I want to use the same model/domain classes in both the Java webservice and the Android application (the webservice uses Maven whereas the Android application uses Gradle).

At the moment I am manually mirroring any changes I make to the model classes in both the Java webservice and the Android project. This is however very tedious and obviously not a good solution.

My questions is how I can solve this issue. I thought about creating a Maven module containing the model classes and importing them in the Java webservice and the Android project. However I am uncertain if this a solution which will work.

Are there any better (and maybe obvious) solutions I am not seeing? Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Is it actually smart to share the whole model classes? I clearly don't want to use all the attributes from the webservice in the Android project (e.g. passwords will never be stored in the Android project but have to be stored in the webservice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a library for your model, and share it between the provider (REST API) and the consumer (your Android app). That could be done with a multi-module maven project, where you can have a module for your model layer and another module for your REST API layer that uses the previous model artifact.

Doing so, you could install the model library in your local repository (or deploy it in whatever centralized repository you may need) and use it from your Android application.

But I would advice you against sharing the model that way, because you would be tight-coupling your consumer and provider at the model level. That would make it harder to evolve them independently.

Comment: I have changed my mind about sharing the model classes and I'll consider your advice! Thank you.